# Schedule Python job to run using Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, scheduling

I'm pretty new to Python and have just created a script that pulls data from an API, which I manually run everyday.  I'd like to automate this, but not on my local machine using Windows Task Scheduler since that will not always be turned on or have internet access.  I've been told that this is possible in Visual Studio.

1.) If so, how can it be done?
2.) If not, how would I go about scheduling this to run on my company's server?

Thanks!

Comment: Related how to schedule a task on Windows: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993(v=ws.11).aspx

Answer (score 0):

VS can't help you with this beyond authoring the task. You will still need a place where your code can run reliably. This would be a good fit for something like Azure functions --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview

You could create a Scheduled function that can run your python script on a schedule.

Comment: I'm sorry - not sure what you mean by authoring the task?  Do you mean I could create a task but not actually schedule it?  Does the "Execute Process task" feature not accomplish scheduling?

Comment: Appreciate your help.  Simply put, all I'm trying to do is schedule the script to run on a company owned server once a day.